# How to print documents using Java?

Tags: java, printing

I have a requirement to print data exactly in a particular position in paper. How can these kind of formatting be done using Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jasper](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/), [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Which kind of data ?

If it's form, the use of reporting library can help you:

- http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports

If it's graphic you can try using 'raw' java api:

- http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html

Answer (score 0):

Or use the Java print API:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mer0322/index.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mer0424.html

Answer (score 0):

If you really need full control, you can print Graphics2D objects directly. See http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/render.html and the next page.

Another possibility would be printing PDF, e.g. using iText. I think exact positioning is possible, but probably harder than using Graphics2D.