# How to print the text from a TextArea using a jButton in java?

Tags: java, swing, printing, textarea, jbutton

How can I print the texts from a TextArea using a jButton? I'm using netbeans, btw. Can anyone help me? It's for my midterm project in school.

Answer (score 1):

use getText() method of textarea to get the text. Use System.out.println() to print it in console, or if not console, follow your approach. Do these things inside the JButton's event handler.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aew)
{
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea();

    String result = text.getText();
}
```

Comment: I mean, literally print from a printer. The code for printing something from the program itself. :(

Comment: OK, please make your questions clear in future. Have a look in here

1. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959064/how-to-print-documents-using-java